# Consuming apis with Retrofit without @PATH

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm consuming from https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all in order to show a country list, but AS throw me an error when using the @PATH, what can i do?

```
public interface ICountryService {

    String ENDPOINT = "https://restcountries.eu";


    @GET("/rest/v1/all")
    Call<List<Country>> getCountry(@Path("country") String country);


}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The country variable is looking for  a {country_id} inside the URL. You should remove the @Path.

You need to do it like:

```
@GET("/rest/v1/all") Call<List<Country>> getCountry();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `/rest/v1/all` endpoint is a list of countries and it does not take a specific country on its path. By adding `@Path("country")` you are trying to compose an url of the form `rest/v1/all/someCountry` which is probably invalid.